# How to add a field many times in Django admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

what is the best way to add a field many times in Django admin panel

i mean how i can add many names in admin panel

i want add many names because i have courses section and i want add Lesson 1 then give it youtube link then add Lesson 2 then give it youtube link etc

i have this code in models.py :

```
from django.db import models

class Courses(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

in the result i want something like that

[image]

any help

Comment: Why would you want the same name repeated many times???

Comment: not 'same name repeated many times' i want add many names because i have courses section and i want add Lesson 1 then give it youtube link then add Lesson 2 then give it youtube link etc ..

Comment: I think you need to be clear on what you have today, what you have tried, and the actual results you want. As it stands, this question is far too woolly to try and answer. See here for guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I edited my question, please re-read it

Comment: You need to look into formsets. If it's multiple URLs to one course, then an inline formset. If it's one course, one URL, but you want to add multiple ones per page, then just a model formset will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you probably have a Lesson model as well, that looks like this:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    youtube_url = models.URLField()
```

In that case, you want an inline formset on the Course model, which we can do with [inline admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects):

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Course, Lesson

class InlineLessons(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Lesson


class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ InlineLessons ]

admin.site.register(Lesson)  # Needed for permissions
admin.site.register(Course, CourseAdmin)
```

Now go to a course in the admin and you can add many lessons below it.

Comment: thanks for replay , your answer helped me but how i can pass data from Course + Lesson models into one html page 
 
i have this code in views.py how i can add Lesson ?




`def course_posts(request,slug):
    course_posts = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
    context = {'course_posts':course_posts}
    return render(request,'course/course_posts_page.html', { 'course_posts': course_posts })`

Comment: also how to pass data to html page

Comment: You already created a new question for that, which is what I was going to suggest as the two are unrelated.

Comment: yes thanks a lot for your help here is my new answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402016/pass-data-from-two-models-into-one-single-html-page-django