# Pass data from two models into one single html page - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i'm facing problem with show data from two models into single html page

i have two models - first called `Course` and second called `Lesson` okay , so i want add course then add lesson in the course and show data in one html page

models.py :

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    app_contect = RichTextField(blank=True,null=True)
    app_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    post_tag = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",choices = COURSE_SECTION)
    objects = SearchManager()
    slug = models.SlugField(default="",blank=True,unique=True,editable=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id or not self.slug:
            super(Course, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.slug = slugify(f"{self.title} {str(self.id)}")
        super(Course, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_image(self):
        if self.app_image and hasattr(self.app_image, 'url'):
            return self.app_image.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-post_date',)


class Lesson(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    youtube_url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog_app.models import Course,Lesson

class InlineLessons(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Lesson

class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ InlineLessons ]

admin.site.register(Lesson)
admin.site.register(Course,CourseAdmin)
```

so how to show data from course and lesson model into one html page ?

```
i tried do this but it's don't work , it just show data from Course model
```

views.py :

```
def course_posts(request,slug):
    lesson = Lesson.objects.all()
    course_posts = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
    context = {'course_posts':course_posts}
    return render(request,'course/course_posts_page.html', { 'course_posts': course_posts,'lesson':lesson })
```

html page :

```
  <h1 id="font_control_for_header_in_all_pages"> {{course_posts.name}} </h1>

    <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0 text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
             {{lesson.name}}
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">

          <iframe width="100%" height="400px" src="{{lesson.youtube_url}}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this don't work , it's show data from `Course` model not from lesson and course

Comment: `lesson` is not a *single* `Lesson` object, it is a `QuerySet` of *all* `Lesson`s, so a "collection".

Comment: okay so what i must edit please

Comment: You should read up on [Reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

Comment: So far you've not accepted a single answer on many questions. Are they not working for you?

Comment: i tried the answer below and it worked fine and i accepted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to display all the lessons associated with a course, so you should modify your view to not made the lesson query.

```py
    def course_posts(request,slug):
        course_posts = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
        context = {'course_posts':course_posts}
        return render(request,'course/course_posts_page.html', { 'course_posts': course_posts })
```

```html
      <h1 id="font_control_for_header_in_all_pages"> {{course_posts.name}} </h1>
    
        <div id="accordion">

        {% for lesson in course_posts.lesson_set.all %}

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0 text-center">
              <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                 {{lesson.name}}
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>
    
          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
    
              <iframe width="100%" height="400px" src="{{lesson.youtube_url}}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

Comment: thanks you very much it's work perfect ! just you forget add `lesson = Lesson.objects.all()` in views.py before this line `course_posts = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)`

Comment: No I didn't. I removed that line on purpose because it performs a database query without then being used. You really don't need to do that lesson query.

Comment: when i remove `lesson = Lesson.objects.all()` it show error when i open page it say `name 'lesson' is not defined` and when i add the previous line it work perfect !

Comment: @KokHyvv Just remove `lesson` from the context - I copied your view & missed that bit, sorry.

Comment: oh yeah don't worry , thanks for your help it work also perfect ❤